# Excel to pandas computation possibilities

Tags: python, pandas

Hello New to python and pandas

I data like this:

```
PORTFOLIO       DATE  Initial Investment
          A 2018-02-27  3.0
          B 2018-02-28  2.1
          C 2018-03-01  1.5
          D 2018-03-02  0.4
.
.
.
.
```

I have to converted this to investment value at 6% pa appreciation year on year.
Output like this: (Y0 is initial investment)

```
Portfolio   Y0    Y1       Y2     Y3    Y4  ….  Y10
A           3    3.18    3.3708             
B          2.1   2.226   2.35956                
C          1.5   1.59    1.6854             
D          0.4   0.424   0.44944
```

Is it possible to do this in pandas in simple way? I am used to excel based calculations.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you already have a dataframe named `df` and with columns `Portfolio` and `Y0`, then you can do:

```
df['Y1'] = df['Y0'] * 1.06
df['Y2'] = df['Y1'] * 1.06
```

and so on.

Comment: This is what I am doing. But, can there be better way?

Comment: You can make it in a loop?